# Some pointers on how to begin VHDL writing

Tags: fpga, vhdl, simulation, synthesis

I'm currently doing some tutorials and reading some books on how to write VHDL. As I'm curious and learn better with hands-on tutorials I'm going to start implementing my projects that will serve me well in the future.

For my first real project I'm trying to implement an `arctg` function followed by an aggregation operator function.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel and I don't want to be further confused and so I'm asking here the following questions:

1. The integer to float and vice-versa with the bits of the mantissa, exponent and integer is necessary right? Isn't there any website where people have already implemented this kind of things and share with the community?
2. I've seen  somewhere that the package `math_real` already has an `ARCTAN`function which accepts a `REAL` which I guess is a float. So:

   2.1. Is this synthesizable? If not why is it even coded?

   2.2. If everything needs to be converted from float to integer in order to be passed between functions, why does `ARCTAN` accept `REAL` and not an integer?

Comment: Real math / types are not synthesizable. Unless you have some vendor-specific smart synthesis tool which is made capable of it. It was coded like many non-synthesizable stuff - for simulation and testing.

Comment: So, these functions are just part of tests to compare the function that one has to make with a non-synthesizable version of it, just for simulation and comparison is that it?

Comment: Yes and no. The no part - it's also for simulating the parts of the system which are not yet implemented, but supposed to do some real math.

Comment: "opencores" has a library you may find useful.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answers guys. @pjc50 I already encountered that website, but the registration process takes a while (some days).
So for integer to float and vice-versa, which is something that literally everyone does in their projects I will need to do everything from scratch?

Comment: Perhaps a fixed point math would be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: If you're starting to do something new, and think 'I need to provide all this infrastructure from scratch', then probably you're not using the right tool for the job, or have chosen the wrong first project for the tool. I call it the 'are you riding the horse in the direction it's going?' question, it's much easier to ride it that way than sideways or backwards. FPGAs excel at digital logic, comparisons, storage, and integer maths. DPS ICs tend to be used for maths with reals. For ARCTAN function, look up CORDIC (wikipedia), that's the natural FPGA implementation, and works with integers.

Comment: "literally everyone does": you'd be surprised how far you can get without it.

Comment: Yeah, that is a very good advice that I didn't thought of. Since to make the `arctg` function I'll apparently need CORDIC, I'll check if that's possible with fixed_point

Comment: Oh okay... Maybe I have the wrong idea about doing this. I was thinking of converting everything to floats and so on but maybe I'll manage to do everything with integers..
Problem will be when I need to read `double floats` from a file, which is my ultimate objective on the VHDL project

Comment: FPGA can't read from file. So probably you do not fully understand the final goal..

Comment: I know, when I say file is for simulation purposes. In the end it will be to read data from sensors.

Comment: So for simulation you can just write a simulated translator. The question is what is the format of the sensor data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VHDL-2008 has synthesisable fixed-point and floating-point libraries, in addition to `ieee.math_real` which is strictly for simulation. You can instantiate the float package with any width of mantissa and exponent, or use the pre-defined float types (roughly IEEE P754). The fixed point package is a better choice for DSP, and usually produces smaller hardware.

These libraries should handle question (1) for you.

For question 2)

1. The `math_real` ARCTAN is used in simulation, not for synthesis.
2. Question makes no sense as you can pass reals to and from functions.